# Apache .htaccess RewriteCond check if remote/external url exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ubuntu-server

I have one server ex01.server.com and I need redirect all files if exist on my cloud cloud.server.com.

All my files is in ex01.server.com and I copy/upload to cloud.server.com only many files, NOT all.

Right now I have this .htaccess to redirect by this don't check if the file is on cloud.server.com.

For example:

**On the ex01.server.com:**

http://ex01.server.com/file/01/my-file01.png

http://ex01.server.com/file/01/my-file02.png

http://ex01.server.com/file/01/my-file03.png

**On the cloud.server.com:**

http://cloud.server.com/file/01/my-file01.png

http://cloud.server.com/file/01/my-file02.png

***Note: that on cloud.server.com I don't have the file/01/my-file02.png***

Always my clients go direct to ex01.server.com and in this with .htaccess I redirect or not.

**This is my .htaccess on ex01.server.com:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond http://cloud.server.com/$1 -U
   RewriteRule ^(files/.*)$ http://cloud.server.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
 </IfModule>
```

I thing that using -U ( checks if test string is a valid url and user is authorized to access it ) can be the solution but don't work for me.

Comment: You will need to use server code e.g. PHP to check if the file exists on a remote URL. If it's not on the same server, I don't believe that will be possible.

Comment: @PanamaJack Thanks, but the system I don't to do any changes. Only I can modify the apache / .htaccess.

Comment: Then u will have to make a list of all valid files, and "manually" redirect each one of them. Yes lots of work.

Comment: Thanks very much but they are 367000 files. LOL.